# Custom button not performing action in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

Am trying to add another custom button, and at the same time I want it to trigger certain processes in Django-admin with templates, below is how I have implemented the template :

```
{% extends 'admin/custominlines/change_form.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
 {% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
     {{ block.super }}
       {% if request.GET.edit %}
        <div class="submit-row">
            <input type="submit"  value="Custom button" name="_transition-states">
        </div>
     {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The button does appear however, when I click it , it doesn't show the print I have inserted in the `response_change()` function in the `admin.py`, what am I missing here :

```
 def response_change(self, request, obj):
        if '_transition-states' in request.POST:
            print("am working")
        return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

When I click the button it just routes back to the previous page.

Comment: What is the template you're extending? Is it based on `admin/change_form.html`?

Comment: Hey @Melvyn yes

Comment: Works for me: I get "am working" on the console as expected. Are you expecting this to show up in admin page?

Comment: I want it to print in the console but it's not

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, sorry :( Instead of printing, perhaps throw an exception, so you are certain it's not a logging issue. So use `raise ValueError('am working')` instead of print.